# Estimate current progress through set knowing only start and end

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce, statistics, probability

How can you estimate your progress iterating through a set knowing only the first and last items and not number of items?

```
AAAAAAA
....
....
....?
....
....
ZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

First and last items are guaranteed to be the lexicographic minimum and maximum of the entire set. The distribution of item values can be assumed to be close to uniform. The order in which you receive items is not known and could be unpredictable or could be in order. Items are guaranteed to be unique.

It's okay if the estimate fluctuates as long as it generally gets closer to 99.999% over time.

This reminds of me of the [German tank problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) except that there isn't (as far as I know) a way to subtract or get the distance between items in lexicographic order. For instance, I was thinking of taking the max item yet received and compare it to the last item, but I don't know a way to get the "distance" between arbitrary items.

CONTEXT: I've got mappers in a mapreduce job consuming these keys and without being able to report percent progress the tasktracker assumes that the tasks are getting stuck and starts spawning speculative redundant maps over the same data.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your requirements, but if the distribution is known and the order is completely unpredictable, the problem seems unsolvable. No amount of independent samples from the same distribution can give you any new information about their total number. The same goes if the samples are unique (and thus not independent), but their possible orders are uniformly distributed. I don't think you can estimate the progress without having at least some information about the order of items.

Answer (score 1):

You find the distance with the help of permutation rank:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lexicographic-rank-of-a-string/

What you would do is calculate rank of each string and subtracting the distance.

Comment: does this works for strings of possibly different lengths? Though as as heuristic I could probably use the first *n* characters to make the problem simpler

Comment: Isn't lexicographic rank applicable only to comparing a string to it's own permutations? Ranks of different string do not necessarily increase in lexicographic order. For example, rank of “cba” is 6, and rank of "def" is 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat a string "S<sub>1</sub>S<sub>2</sub>...S<sub>n</sub>" as a number that is equal to S<sub>1</sub>/N + S<sub>2</sub>/N^2 + ... + S<sub>n</sub>/N^n, where N is the size of your alphabet. In other words, characters of a string are digits after comma of N-ary representation of that number.

Then you can use a difference between these numbers as a distance between strings, at it is monotone relative to the lexicographic order.